# Getting ruby enviroment variable DATABASE_URL in Java Android Application

Tags: java, android, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I've Rails app in heroku and created database. I can see it's url when I use `heroku config`. Also I have Java android  application which has 2 activities. I create database class there as docs say:

```
public class Database
{
    public Database()
    {
        System.out.println(System.getenv("DATABASE_URL"));
        try {
            Connection connection=getConnection();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private static Connection getConnection() throws URISyntaxException, SQLException {
        URI dbUri = new URI(System.getenv("DATABASE_URL"));

        String username = dbUri.getUserInfo().split(":")[0];
        String password = dbUri.getUserInfo().split(":")[1];
        String dbUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://" + dbUri.getHost() + ':' + dbUri.getPort() + dbUri.getPath();
        System.out.println(username);
        return DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, username, password);
    }
}
```

And create database object in my Activity:

```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Database database=new Database();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
```

But I see null instead of url. Well it's predictable because they are two different application. So what is the proprer way to get `DATABASE_URL` in my Java android app? Or I should just copy database's url in Java variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that direct connect from Android app to DB is quite bad idea.

If you really need it, you can fetch it from heroku app via some http api.

But it is better to use HTTP API for all interaction between android app and db, via your ruby app.

Comment: Can you advice any tutorials then?

Comment: Actually it is basics of rails.
Just read guides, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/
Create controller DbController#db_url if you want connect directly to DB. Or create some REST resources, guides have all necessary info.